# PACKET DROPPED - Finding out which packets are dropped?

Tags: networking, network-programming, packet-capture, tcpdump

How do I print which packets are dropped by by the interface ???

I have an interface wherein RX packets are dropped , see below :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr DE:AD:BE:EF:42:46  
          inet addr:192.168.122.86  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dcad:beff:feef:4246/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          **RX packets:10963521 errors:0 dropped:1006 overruns:0 frame:0**
          TX packets:6221974 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3108701252 (2.8 GiB)  TX bytes:3842229777 (3.5 GiB)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0xe000
```

Comment: You can't, because they have been dropped. Your question makes no actual sense.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can enable dropped packets logging:

Step 1. Change Windows Firewall configuration:

```
auditpol.exe /set /SubCategory:"Filtering Platform Packet Drop" /failure:enable
```

Step 2. Restart firewall service

```
net stop MPSSVC
net start MPSSVC
```

More info on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754714(v=ws.10).aspx.

Comment: That's not the type of packet dropping to which the original question was referring.  It's referring to capturing network traffic, but not being able to see all the packets because they arrive too fast and fill up the buffer for captured packets, so some of them can't be put into that buffer and made available to capturing programs.